# Using linker flag to change stack size on M1 Apple laptop

Tags: c++, c, cmake, apple-m1

Running cmake (Apple M1 Max, macOS Monterey, 64GB Memory) yielded the following error message:

```
ld: -stack_size must be <= 512MB
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

On an Intel processor Mac laptop, the following linker flag worked to resolve the issue.

```
if (APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-stack_size,0x100000000")
endif (APPLE)
```

On the new M1 processor Mac laptop, it doesn't seem to work.  Any hints why?

Thanks!

Comment: are the units there bytes? 0x1 0000 0000 is 4GB, which is assuredly larger than 512MB and the error makes sense. I don't know why it worked before, automatic ceiling perhaps? Try 0x2000 0000, that's 512MB anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked after changing it to 512MB.  Still a mystery why it worked before.

Comment: hmm, yeah I have no idea. Maybe Intel has some architecture that allows for huge stack sizes? My best guess would be that it capped any huge values at whatever the max allowed value was instead of throwing an error. Curious, why do you want these huge stack sizes? On linux the default I've always seen is 8MB (so also not understanding why CPU architecture would matter, maybe it's just a coincidence).